# How to place toolbar above (or below) scrolling tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview, scroll

**ENVIRONMENT:**

- Xcode 7.3.1
- iOS 9.3

**OBJECTIVE:**

  A scrollable table view with a toolbar (or distinct buttons) in a fixed location (either above or below) relative to the scrolling table.

**STORYBOARD:**

  Originally I just had the tableview and added a toolbar to it, however the toolbar is sitting within the tableview.
  I later found this option for the Bottom Bar: Opaque Toolbar, but cannot figure out how to utilize it / move my toolbar into the space provided (which looks like what I want)
    [image: storyboard]

**CURRENT RESULTS:**

  If I only have a few cells, e.g.: 5 or 10, then the results are “okay”, but not “great”:
    [image: okay]

However, if I have a large number of cells, e.g.: 20, then the problem I was trying to avoid is immediately apparent:

  [image: bad]

**QUERY:**

Can I accomplish what I want from within the Xcode UI?

- If so, can someone provide some pointers / steps that I need to take to do so?

Or do I need to do this within the Swift code?

- Again, pointers / steps / generic code example gratefully appreciated.

---

***WRT 2016-09-15 Edit in Answer #1***

> Embed the initial View Controller (the one with the buttons) in an `UINavigationController`.

I don't see how to do that, as the only thing I seem to be able to embed within the navigation controller is a **Tab Bar Controller**

  [image: embed]

> If not already created, make a `UITableViewController` class and link it to your Table View Controller.

I already have `class ExistingLocationsViewController: UITableViewController { ... }` (and a `class ExistingLocationTableViewCell: UITableViewCell { ... }`) linked, I believe, appropriately

> Add this code to the class in order to make the Toolbar appear and disappear when you are viewing the Table View:
>
> ```
>     import UIKit
>     class ViewController: UITableViewController {
>         override func viewDidLoad() {
>             super.viewDidLoad()
>             navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false
>         }
>         override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
>             navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = true
>         }
>     }
> ```
>
> This should be all you'll have to do. If you want to edit the toolbar make it visible while you are editing it and afterwards hide it again.

FYI, in my Xcode, iOS version, the property appears to be named `toolbarHidden`  (*not* `**isT**oolbarHidden`)

---

***ANOTHER APPROACH (2016-09-17)***
Going back a step (or two), I noticed an option with the Table View Controller and tried to make use of it, but it didn't seem to work. See image (and text within) for details:

  [image: embed]

When I run the app, it doesn't seem to make any difference (again, see image):

  [image: embed]

Am I doing something wrong?, or completely misunderstanding the Xcode interface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the easiest ways to add a toolbar to any view is by embedding it in a `NavigationViewController`. All this can be done without code:

1. Take the View Controller that you currently have (I assume the `UITableViewController`) and under **Editor -> Embed In** select **Navigation Controller**.
   [image]

   2. Select the newly created Navigation Controller. In the utilities bar under **Bar Visibility**, select **Toolbar** to be shown. If needed you can also keep the Navigation Bar, else turn it off.
      [image]
   3. Now you are able to modify the Toolbar in `UITableViewController`. Just drag the different Toolbar items (Bar Button Item, Fixed Space Bar Button Item, Flexible Bar Button Item) onto the Toolbar as you please. Be aware, you can't move the toolbar and you can only change its style in the `NavigationViewController`.
      [image]

**EDIT:**
Since you have a different initial View Controller, I would recommend you solving the issue slightly differently. This will require a little bit of code:

1. Embed the initial View Controller (the one with the buttons) in an `UINavigationController`. Remove any other Navigation Controllers. Your buttons should simply have a segue that show the `UITableViewController`. Disable the Toolbar in the Navigation Controller and as before, it's up to you to enable the Navigation Bar (I would recommend it).
   [image]
2. If not already created, make a `UITableViewController` class and link it to your Table View Controller. 
   [image]
3. Add this code to the class in order to make the Toolbar appear and disappear when you are viewing the Table View:

   ```
   import UIKit

   class ViewController: UITableViewController {

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false
       }

       override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
           navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = true
       }

   }
   ```

This should be all you'll have to do. If you want to edit the toolbar make it visible while you are editing it and afterwards hide it again.

Comment: I hope this helped! Do not hesitate to ask me for further information :)

Comment: I like it - but I think I'm missing something because it's failing.  This is probably my fault for not providing a fuller picture of my storyboard.  I have an initial `ViewController` which currently has 3 buttons on it.  Each of the buttons segue's to [what was] the `UITableViewController`, each with a distinct `identifier` - which will eventually be used by my code.
With the changes I made as per your suggestion, the segue fails with an error: "Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x109452860) to 'gj3.ExistingLocationsViewController' (0x107ac19e8)."

Comment: I also considered using a standard View and adding a Navigation Bar and Table View to it (assuming that the table view would still scroll within its region) - but then I wasn't sure how to amend my code since the View would not be based on a `UITableViewController`, and I wasn't sure if I could use my custom `UITableVIewController` class for the applied Table View.
In general, I like your idea better because it *should* (I believe) mean less changes to my code - but I have to figure out how to resolve the segue issue

Comment: If the answer has helped you, please mark it as correct.

Comment: WRT ***2016-09-15 Edit*** - see edit in original posting (since I cannot format my response properly here)

Comment: I was using Xcode 8 and therefor the syntax is slightly different, but you seem to have already found the appropriate syntax for your version. I'm a bit confused with the other issue. What I can see by the image is that you are trying to embed a `NavigationController` in another `NavigationController` which is not possible. I don't quite understand the structure of your storyboard. If you already have a `NavigationController` as it seems like by that image you don't need another one.

Comment: You said I should "*Take the View Controller that you currently have (I assume the `UITableViewController`) and under **Editor -> Embed** In select **Navigation Controller***" - which I have done. So I have my initial `UIViewController`, then my `UITableViewController` with an embedded `UINavigationController`, You then said: "*Embed the initial View Controller (the one with the buttons) in an `UINavigationController`*" -  but there was no option to do so.  Or was I misunderstanding your suggestion? I don't see how to embed a `UIViewController` in the `UINavigationController`.

Comment: Taking a side-route, see: ***ANOTHER APPROACH (2016-09-17)*** near the bottom of the above posting.

Comment: This doesn't actually add a Toolbar. It used for when embedding the `ViewController` in a `NavigationController` only in code. In the approach I described it is done directly in the storyboard and the Toolbar is therefore shown automatically.

Comment: Lets start over, remove **ALL** `UINavigationControllers`, so u should only have your `UITableViewController` and your `UIViewController` with the 3 buttons that link to the `UITableViewController`. Now embed the `UIViewController` with the 3 buttons in a `UINavigationController`. Continue following the instructions of the 2nd approach in my answer. Remember that the code is slightly different in your version of Xcode.

Comment: Okay - let me ask the "dumb question": ***How*** do I *embed* the `UIViewController` with the 3 buttons in a `UINavigationController`?  And is the same `UINavigationController` that I previously embedded into the `UITableViewController` or a different one?  If different - do I keep the one I embedded into the `UITableViewController` or do I get rid of that one first?

Comment: Ah!  Okay - it now looks like it's working.  I want to do a bit more verification and compose a summarization (to help the next poor fool like me :-)  **Thanks Much!!**

Comment: No Problem, glad i could help :)

Answer (score 1):

**RESOLUTION (with *much* thanks to Christoph!)**

1. **Preliminary Work**

   - My work began with a Single Page app consisting of the default `UIViewController` (`ViewController.swift`).
   - I added buttons to the view (and tweaked their appearance and such)

       [image]
   - I added a `UITableViewController` and created my own custom class for it (`MyTableViewController.swift`)
   - In the table's *Prototype Cells* I added a couple of labels to populate with the data, and created my own custom class for the cells (`MyTableViewCell.swift`)
   - I then created segues from the buttons in the initial `UIViewController` to the table in the `UITableViewController`

     - Each segue has a unique `Identifier` (*this will be used later, but for now it's to allow the id to be passed from the initial view to the table view*)

         [image]

       At this point, the app "worked", but I wanted to have some buttons (either at the top or bottom of the table) to act on whatever data was selected within the table.  When I started this thread, I had added a Toolbar, but it basically pinned itself to just below the prototype cell and when there were more rows of data than would fit on a single screen, it too was scrolled off and didn't appear until the list was scrolled all the way to the end.
2. **Fix - a.k.a. Christoph to the Rescue**

   - Start by *embedding* the initial view within a *Navigation Controller*

     - I was initially confused about what was getting embedded into what, hopefully this picture makes it much clearer

         [image]
   - The result of doing this, modifies the Storyboard thusly:

       [image]
   - I then went to *My Table View Controller Scene* and inserted a *Navigation Item* into the space that now showed up at the top of that view:

       [image]
   - To this, I was able to add *Bar Button Item*s:

       [image]
   - And with a variety of custom code (*more on this below*) was able to get this:

       [image]
3. **Code**

- At this point, the code for `ViewController.swift` is relatively simple:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var b1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var b2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var b3: UIButton!
    var buttonId: String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        b1.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        b2.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        b3.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let destination      = segue.destinationViewController as! MyTableViewController
        destination.buttonId = segue.identifier
    }
}
```

- The code for `MyTableViewCell.swift` is also pretty simple (at least for now):

```
import UIKit

class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var l1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var l2: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        // Add bordering to bottom of each cell
        let border = CALayer()
        let width = CGFloat(1.0)
        border.borderColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - width, width:  self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
        border.borderWidth = width
        self.layer.addSublayer(border)
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

- The code for `MyTableViewController.swift` is, on the other hand, more complex - perhaps because there's just more of it:

```
import UIKit

class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var b1: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var b2: UIBarButtonItem!
    var buttonId: String!
    var oldRow = -1
    // The data below is clearly just for testing, eventually this should be pulled from file or DB
    var locationList: [LocationObject] = [
        LocationObject(name: "name-01", address: "addr-1", selected: false),
        LocationObject(name: "name-02", address: "addr-2", selected: false),
        LocationObject(name: "name-03", address: "addr-3", selected: false),
        LocationObject(name: "name-04", address: "addr-3", selected: false),
        LocationObject(name: "name-05", address: "addr-3", selected: false),
        LocationObject(name: "name-06", address: "addr-3", selected: false),
        LocationObject(name: "name-07", address: "addr-3", selected: false),
        LocationObject(name: "name-08", address: "addr-3", selected: false),
        LocationObject(name: "name-09", address: "addr-3", selected: false),
        LocationObject(name: "name-10", address: "addr-3", selected: false),
        LocationObject(name: "name-11", address: "addr-1", selected: false),
        LocationObject(name: "name-12", address: "addr-2", selected: false),
        LocationObject(name: "name-13", address: "addr-3", selected: false),
        LocationObject(name: "name-14", address: "addr-3", selected: false),
        LocationObject(name: "name-15", address: "addr-3", selected: false),
        LocationObject(name: "name-16", address: "addr-3", selected: false),
        LocationObject(name: "name-17", address: "addr-3", selected: false),
        LocationObject(name: "name-18", address: "addr-3", selected: false),
        LocationObject(name: "name-19", address: "addr-3", selected: false),
        LocationObject(name: "name-10", address: "addr-3", selected: false),
        ]

    // This embedded class is to support the above data. It may get replaced in final code
    class LocationObject {
        var name:     String!
        var address:  String!
        var selected: Bool!

        init(name: String, address: String, selected: Bool) {
            self.name      = name
            self.address   = address
            self.selected  = false
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // code to hide/expose the navbar (top) and toolbar(bottom) when the view loads
        navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false 
        navigationController?.toolbarHidden       = true
    }

   // code to hide the navbar and toolbar when this view goes away
    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
        navigationController?.toolbarHidden       = true 
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return locationList.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("resultCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
        let row  = indexPath.row
        let item = locationList[row]

        cell.l1.text = item.name
        cell.l2.text = item.address

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell                   = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
        let row                    = indexPath.row
        cell.accessoryType         = .None
        locationList[row].selected = false
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        b1.enabled = true
        let cell                   = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
        let row                    = indexPath.row
        locationList[row].selected = !locationList[row].selected
        cell.accessoryType         = (locationList[row].selected == true) ? .Checkmark : .None
        cell.highlighted           = false
        cell.setHighlighted(false, animated: true)

        // TOGGLE SELECTION
        if oldRow == row {
            b1.enabled = false
            let oldIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: oldRow, inSection: 0)
            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(oldIndexPath, animated: true)
            oldRow = -1
        }
        else {
            oldRow = row
        }
    }
}
```

And that, in a nutshell is it. I'm still in the early stages of developing my app - somehow I'm reasonably sure I'll be posting some more questions regarding the implementation as I move forward, but hopefully the above will help others who might be struggling with the same, or similar, issue(s).

Thanks again to *Christoph* for providing the much needed directions regarding embedding the view into a navigation view controller and such.